Pyodbc SQL Server add a timeout
I would like some help in adding a timeout value to my SQL query which is run using the Python code.
Details:
I have a Python code that makes a connection to the MS SQL server using Pyodbc library. It then runs a query, sometimes the query takes more than 60 seconds however, I need to have a mandatory timeout of 40 seconds.
My code snippet
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

# Define the connection string
conn_str = ("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
    "SERVER=your_server_name;"
    "DATABASE=your_database_name;"
    "UID=your_username;"
    "PWD=your_password"
)
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
incremental_sql_query = "some sql query"
table_df = pd.read_sql(incremental_sql_query, conn)

I have tried using some of the below options to test the timeout:

Using the cursor instead of the pd.read_sql method

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.timeout = 40  # 40 seconds


Adding a timeout parameter to the connection string

Timeout=40;

But seems none of them are respecting the 40 seconds value as the query runs for more than my expected timeout.
Does pyodbc provide a built-in method to set a query execution timeout directly?
I am having a hard time finding this solution which otherwise should be quite straightforward.
OR is there any other method through which I can achieve this?
Can someone please help?

Have you tried setting the timeout on the connection object before creating your cursor(s)?

You can't set statement timeouts (aka. command timeouts) via ODBC connection strings, only the connection timeout is exposed at this level. Statement timeouts are typically configured on a per cursor basis via SQLSetStmtAttr with the SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT attribute, but pyodbc doesn't handle this correctly on the cursor, instead new cursors inherit this setting from the connection object's timeout property.

In your particular case, just set conn.timeout = 40 before calling .read_sql_query()
